VBA in excel stops executing automatically when sheets are switched
I created a simple countdown timer in Excel
and below is the code
Public interval As Date
Sub timer()
    interval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    If Range("I3").Value = 0 Then Exit Sub    
    Range("I3") = Range("I3") - TimeValue("00:00:01")  
    Application.OnTime interval, "timer"    
End Sub

Sub stop_timer()
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=interval, Procedure:="timer", Schedule:=False
End Sub

I 
I run the timer and it starts the countdown. But if I switch sheets in excel it automatically stops and I have to run it again.
Please suggest me a way to run the countdown timer even when I switch sheets.
I'm using the latest excel version

Consider to define the worksheet of the range I3. Otherwise the range refers to the active sheet

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Sub Test()
    Sleep 1000 '1 second
End Sub

Unless you have to do something in Excel while waiting?
